# SIFR 3 NOT RENDERING IE7

Tags: sifr, flash-cs4, sifr3

I am building a site right now using the new siFR3 it works perfectly on FF & Chrome but not on IE7 to [view click here](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/phil2010/)

Comment: You might try detailing the problem you are running into

Comment: Hi Chris I couldn't go any deeper than that as I followed the steps thoroughly from http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/How+to+use adn it works perfectly but not on IE. It doesn't render the flash it gives it a georgia type font with a dark gray color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found out what was the problem all it was watch my old code that doesn't work in IE:

```
    sIFR.replace(officinaWhite, {
  selector: '#boxes h1', wmode: 'transparent',
  css: '.sIFR-root { color:#ffffff; }',
});

sIFR.replace(officina, {  
  selector: '#content h2, #rightCol2 h2, #rightCol h2', wmode: 'transparent',
  css: '.sIFR-root { color:#000000; }',
});
```

and this is the code that fixed it:

```
    sIFR.replace(officinaWhite, {
  selector: '#boxes h1', wmode: 'transparent',
  css: ['.sIFR-root { color:#ffffff; }']
});

sIFR.replace(officina, {  
  selector: '#content h2, #rightCol2 h2, #rightCol h2', wmode: 'transparent',
  css: ['.sIFR-root { color:#000000; }']
});
```

it is only missing the parenthesis under the css:['.sIFR-root { color:#000000; }'] no commmas in the end.

Comment: The [] are optional if there's just one string. The comma before `});` was the problem, and you removed it.

Comment: I removed it before putting the "[]" but nothing happends so yeah it was really weird.

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing the errors: [Here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.testground.idghosting.com%2Fphil2010%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and see if that helps.

Making sure your site is W3C compliant can be a major help in fixing troublesome quirks.

Comment: Pretty serious list.  Nice catch.

Comment: @Chris Lively Not really, they all seem to be pretty minor errors. Missing alt tags and forgetting to end non-closing tags with />...

Comment: Well sorry, that is about the extent of my help, I don't even have access to IE7 anymore. (I use linux)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no trailing comma before a closing brace in the config. These are illegal in IE's JavaScript engine.

Comment: what do you mean this is all I have 

sIFR.replace(officinaWhite, {
  selector: '#boxes h1', wmode: 'transparent',
  css: '.sIFR-root { color:#ffffff; }',
});

sIFR.replace(officina, {  
  selector: '#content h2, #rightCol2 h2, #rightCol h2', wmode: 'transparent',
  css: '.sIFR-root { color:#000000; }'
});